# undefined method `session' for ApplicationController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am practicing with rails and I was in the topic of "session" and I get the message 
"undefined method `session' for ApplicationController:Class"

please help me

this is the code
***(controller aplication)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  session :session_key => 'ruby_cookies'
end
```

***(controller when I want to create the cookies)

```
class RegistroController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def login
    if request.post?
      p_user = User.new(params[:user])
      user   = User.find_by_nombre_and_password(p_user.nombre, p_user.password)
      if user
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        flash[:notice]    = "se ha identificado correctamente"
        redirect_to home_url
      else
        flash[:notice] = "se incorrecto psps"
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end
  end

  def logout
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "adios sayonara"
    redirect_to home_url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really hard to read, but the issue is probably related to this line where it looks like it's trying to call a method "session" and pass it a key/value pair.

```
session :session_key => 'ruby_cookies'
```

This doesn't appear to be within any sort of controller action. Normally you would set a session value with `session[:my_value] = 'value'` and read it with `session[:my_value]`, just like a normal hash.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `ApplicationController` doesn't belong there. It belongs in a configuration file, for example `config/environment.rb`, where it would read something like this:

```
config.action_controller.session = {     
  :session_key => 'ruby_cookies'
}
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html for much more detail.